# Hotel restaurant menu ordering process

Tags: architecture, web-applications, project-management, development-process

With my team I’m facing a problem.

For a hotel, we are asked to develope a cloud application that will let guests taking orders from hotel restaurant menu trough their devices.

To access the menu, guest will scan a qr code (or click on a link on the web site of the hotel) and will be redirected to an authentication form where to enter name, surname and room nr. Guests have been previously registered with above details in the app from hotel staff.

Guests in a room can be more then one but only one of them is registered from the Staff into the application. So, details of that person (only that one) will be the ones trough which menus are accessible filling an authentication form.

Guests have food items included in the price they payed for the room, so no food item prices are displayed into the menu.

But from every menu, a single guest can choose only one food item per menu heading. Ordering more will be charged extra.

For every menu, kitchen staff have to receive only one order per room (no matter how many guests are in the room). This one order has to list, all together, food items choices of all room guests.

So, for guests in one room, access to menus trough authentication form can be from more then one device, in different times or at the same time.

Imagine a room with 3 guests and everyone of them access, with his own mobile, the dinner menu to place his own order.

Guest nr. 1 (let’s says the one registered in the App) accesses first and in his order he chooses 2 food items from ‘Starters‘ menu heading. From the App logic, an order from a room with 3 guests can contain 3 food items choices for every menu heading. So, Guest nr. 1 will be not asked to pay extra when he submits his order.

After a while Guest nr. 2 accesses (using details of Guest nr. 1 to fill authentication form) to browse the menu in order to make his choices. He chooses only one food item from ‘Starters‘ menu heading. Still, from the App logic, no extra charges have to be applyed to the room because total food items ordered in starters menu heading is 3.

Finally, Guest nr. 3 access (also using details of Guest nr. 1 to fill authentication form) and also chooses one food item from ‘Starters‘. When he submits his order an alert inform him that he has to pay for the starter because already 3 of them were ordered.

So basically a situation like the one above, says that:
a) The app can’t distinguish which of that single room guests is placing the order (they all access with the credentials of the only guest registered).
b) Because of “a“ the app can’t manage properly that food items that are ordered as extra.

We thought already to some solutions but none of them is really convincing.

1. Let the guest that accessed to indicate for which guest is placing the order with the options:
   Guest 1,
   Guest 2,
   Guest 3,
   All the guests in the room.

2-A) If a second guest access the menu after that a first one of the same room has already placed his order, an alert will inform him that an order has been already placed from another guest of the same room and he is asked if he wants to modify it adding (or deleting) food items.
If he chooses ‘Modify‘ a version of the menu with info of first guest choices is displayed to him.
When second guest makes his choices he just updates first guest’s order.

2-A case img

[image: 2-A case]

2-B) If a second guest try to access in the same moment in wich a first guest already accessed the menu, this second guest will be able only to see the menu but not to order from it. An alert will inform him that it’s because another guest is placing his order in that moment and the same alert will ask him to place the order later. When the second guest access later, when the first guest already placed his order, then the process of 2-A will happen.

2-B case img

[image]

As I told, none of above solutions is really convincing us because, in our opinion, they put end user in front of too many choices and alert. We are looking for some ideas that we could not have considered.

Comment: Why can't you just say that the guests have to talk to each other and make *one* order? And if the kitchen staff have not seen the order, they can edit the order.

Comment: Back in the days before apps room service orders were charged to the room. Don’t make logging in a huge pain for no reason.

Comment: Not showing prices when actually charging for (additional) items is liable to land you in legal trouble.

Comment: Also, this is not a question. It's a request for coming up with ideas for your UI. Especially given the "reply answer" you posted, it seems like you're trying to cooperatively develop ideas, rather than ask a concrete question and receive a concrete answer.

Comment: After all is said and done, are you charging these guests separately? Or is the bill paid in a single go? Because why spend time differentiating who gets what when it all gets lumped into a single order and bill anyway? I have yet to come across a hotel that differentiates billing between multiple guests in a room.

Comment: _"b) Because of “a“ the app can’t manage properly that food items that are ordered as extra."_ How so? Are you telling me that if the same guest makes multiple orders, you're also not capable of realizing that this guest has ordered many things already? If so, that's a huge flaw in elementary data reading. If not, then I don't see why using a different device for subsequent orders is any different.

Comment: the simple solution would be, allow only one device login per room. and Whenever a user places one order a popup should come, showing this is your nTH free order of Mth.
Suppose they cross their free item limit then your list of the menus should show the price of each item.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone for contributions.
As Bart suggested, the root of the problem stays in the authentication part.
Record on how many guests are in the room is a part of the registration process (sorry, I forgot to indicate it in my post). Registration form will have inputs like guest name, guest surname and, of course, nr. of guests in the room. From this last input the system will recognize wich is the maximum nr. of food items per menu headings per room before charging extras. E.g: in case of 3 guests an order can contain a maximum of 3 food items per menu heading...

Comment: ...But still, in my opinion, is not very end-user (guests or hotel staff) friendly because it forces both to too many interactions with UI..

Comment: About the legal trouble of not showing prices, before sending the order to kitchen staff a resume of it will be displayed to the guest with all choosed food items. In that resume extra items will be also listed with their prices and with the choice for guest to cancel them from the menu or to pay them extra.

Comment: About using one device to login, the idea would probably solve the problem but guests in the hotel are not always together. Maybe one is in the SPA and the other one is on the beach. This (common) situation will bother the guests if everytime, to order their food, they are obliged to meet. About this specific condition, it has also to be said that often in the hotel and for those menus included in room prices, guests have to order their meal within a certain time. They can’t order the dinner in the moment they sit for eating it. They are requested to order it before...

Comment: ...And in that ‘before‘ time frame they can be together, so using one device to order will not be a problem, but they can be not together and then start the problem with using one mobile...

Answer (score 2):

The root of your problems seems to lie in the authentication part, where you don't distinguish between different guests in the same room.

The hotel mush have a record how many guests are staying in each room, even if they don't have all their names. This means the staff can actually register each guest with your system, using the room number, the name the reservation was made under and the name of each guest staying in that room. If the guest's name is not known, just use a default placeholder like "Guest N".

On the authentication page, each person has to indicate which guest they are and they might get the option to replace the "Guest N" identifier put in by the hotel staff with their own name.

With having a login per guest, rather than per room, it also becomes easier to automatically merge orders from different guests in the same room or even to accept them in parallel.